# Trying to convert Access Insert query into MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to convert an Access INSERT query into a MySQL Pass Through Query but am not very familiar with MySQL.  I know my syntax is off, but I don't know exactly what the problem is.

**ACCESS VERSION:**

```
INSERT INTO [tblHistoryThruToday RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR] ( [STUDENT ID], [ADVISOR ID], [COURSE TERM], [BLANK ADV TERM], [BLANK ADV TYPE], [BLANK DEPARTMENT], [BLANK PRIMARY ID], SOURCEFILE, [TIMESTAMP] )

SELECT [tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR].[STUDENT ID], [tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR].[ADVISOR ID], [tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR].[COURSE TERM], [tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR].[BLANK ADV TERM], [tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR].[BLANK ADV TYPE], [tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR].[BLANK DEPARTMENT], [tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR].[BLANK PRIMARY ID], [tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR].SOURCEFILE, [tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR].TIMESTAMP

FROM [tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR];
```

**My attempt at MySQL** (I do have the ` marker on both sides of my table names, but you might not be able to see them in preview)

```
INSERT INTO `tblHistoryThruToday RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR` (‘STUDENT ID’, ‘ADVISOR ID’,’COURSE TERM’, ‘BLANK ADV TERM’,’BLANK ADV TYPE’, ‘BLANK DEPARTMENT’, ‘BLANK PRIMARY ID’, ‘SOURCEFILE’, ‘TIMESTAMP’ )

SELECT `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`.‘STUDENT ID’, `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`.‘ADVISOR ID’, `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`.‘COURSE TERM’, `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`.‘BLANK ADV TERM’, `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`.‘BLANK ADV TYPE’, `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`.‘BLANK DEPARTMENT’, `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`.’BLANK PRIMARY ID’, `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`.‘SOURCEFILE’, `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`.‘TIMESTAMP’

FROM `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`;
```

Comment: Those table names, with spaces and dashes and different kinds of case, are developer rage inducing. Can't you come up with something more concise and easier to read?

Comment: Let's try this more generic version but addresses the same issue.  "Table A" and "Table B" are both tables, which unfortunately, have spaces in the names.

INSERT INTO `Table A` (‘STUDENT ID’, ‘ADVISOR ID’)

SELECT `Table B`.‘STUDENT ID’, `Table B`.‘ADVISOR ID’

FROM `Table B`;

Answer (score 0):

I have changed `‘` to **`**

Try this

```
INSERT INTO `tblHistoryThruToday RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR` (`STUDENT ID`, `ADVISOR ID`,`COURSE TERM`, `BLANK ADV TERM`,`BLANK ADV TYPE`, `BLANK DEPARTMENT`, `BLANK PRIMARY I`, `SOURCEFILE`, `TIMESTAMP` )

SELECT `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`.`STUDENT ID`, `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`.`ADVISOR ID`, `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`.`COURSE TERM`, `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`.`BLANK ADV TERM`, `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`.`BLANK ADV TYPE`, `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`.`BLANK DEPARTMENT`, `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`.`BLANK PRIMARY ID`, `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`.`SOURCEFILE`, `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`.`TIMESTAMP`

FROM `tblHistory - RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR`;
```

Comment: Correct on the apostrophe part -- I switched that out for `

Comment: I did get this version to work:

INSERT INTO `tblHistoryThruToday RETAIN-STU-ADVISOR` ( `STUDENT ID`, `ADVISOR ID`, `COURSE TERM`, `BLANK ADV TERM`, `BLANK ADV TYPE`, `BLANK DEPARTMENT`, `BLANK PRIMARY ID`, `SOURCEFILE`)
SELECT `STUDENT ID`, `ADVISOR ID`, `COURSE TERM`, `BLANK ADV TERM`, `BLANK ADV TYPE`, `BLANK DEPARTMENT`, `BLANK PRIMARY ID`, `SOURCEFILE`
FROM retain.`tblhistorythrutoday retain-stu-advisor` ;


What I needed was the database name "retain" after "FROM"